# Plotly: Plot Polygons

Tags: python, plotly

I have some points (`X0, Y0`), that define a polygon. `X0, Y0` are 1D-arrays.
With `plotly`

```
 polygon = go.Scatter(
        x=X0,
        y=Y0,
        showlegend=False,
        mode="lines",
        fill="toself",
        line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2),
        )
```

The results looks not as expected, so I guess I need to somehow sort the points first.

Any idea how I could go about this?

(Ignore the red point.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the order of your points. I have made an example with the same points but organized them differently (different positions in the array).

```py
fig = make_subplots(1,3, subplot_titles=("polygon0", "polygon1", "polygon2"))

X0 = [25, 50, 38, 40]
Y0 = [20, 40, 60, 25]

X1 = [25, 38, 50, 40]
Y1 = [20, 60, 40, 25]

X2 = [25, 38, 50, 40, 25]
Y2 = [20, 60, 40, 25, 20]


polygon0 = go.Scatter(
        x=X0,
        y=Y0,
        showlegend=False,
        mode="lines",
        fill='toself',
        line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2)
        )  

polygon1 = go.Scatter(
        x=X1,
        y=Y1,
        showlegend=False,
        mode="lines",
        fill='toself',
        line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2)
        )  

polygon2 = go.Scatter(
        x=X2,
        y=Y2,
        showlegend=False,
        mode="lines",
        fill='toself',
        line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2)
        )  

fig.add_trace(polygon0, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(polygon1, row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(polygon2, row=1, col=3)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[20, 55])
fig.show()
```

[image]

As you can see in the figure polygon 0 and polygon 1 are very different althought are constructed from the same scatter points. The only difference in the arrays is that points 2-(50, 40) and 3-(38, 60) are changed in the array X1 Y1, (2 becomes 3 and 3 becomes 2).

Finally, if you want to close your polygon, you can add an extra point to your arrays equivalent to point 0 (polygon2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is how to sort the points in the right way, in order to get a similar result like your polygon 1.

Comment: If you would have given your points would have been easy, but even the figure you added had no axis values so it was impossible to do more. I would say start changing your position 2 and 3

Comment: that's just a convex hull.  take a look at **shapely** to create a convex hull from an array of points

Answer (score 1):

Adding to answer from **@Tengis** Using **shapely** you can construct a multipoint geometry and from that the convex hull.  That's then simple to use in **plotly**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np

fig = make_subplots(1, 2, subplot_titles=("polygon0", "convex hull"))

X0 = [25, 50, 38, 40]
Y0 = [20, 40, 60, 25]

# 2D array of points that make up convex hull
convex_hull = np.array(
    shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(
        [xy for xy in zip(X0, Y0)]
    ).convex_hull.exterior.coords
)

polygon0 = go.Scatter(
    x=X0,
    y=Y0,
    showlegend=False,
    mode="lines",
    fill="toself",
    line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2),
)

polygon1 = go.Scatter(
    x=convex_hull[:, 0],
    y=convex_hull[:, 1],
    showlegend=False,
    mode="lines",
    fill="toself",
    line=dict(color="LightSeaGreen", width=2),
)

fig.add_trace(polygon0, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(polygon1, row=1, col=2)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[20, 55])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Rob_Raymond. nice didn't new about shapely. This completes my answer and solve the problem. +1

Comment: it's a very useful library for any geometry actions you may want to do.  **geopandas** uses it for many of it's geometric capabilities

Answer (score 0):

There is a project for plotting Shapely geometries, including polygons, using Plotly

- https://github.com/thheildesign/shapely_plotly.

It supports all Shapely geometries, 2D and 3D plotting, and control over colors, lines, markers and fills.

Repeating the example from **@Rob Raymond**:

```
import shapely_plotly
import shapely

X0 = [25, 50, 38, 40]
Y0 = [20, 40, 60, 25]

poly0 = shapely.Polygon(shell=zip(X0,Y0))
# Get convex hull
poly1 = poly0.convex_hull

plot_data0 = []
poly0.plotly_draw2d(plot_data0)
shapely_plotly.show2d(plot_data0)

plot_data1 = []
poly1.plotly_draw2d(plot_data1)
shapely_plotly.show2d(plot_data1)
```

[Original polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prz2P.png)

[Convex Hull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI9ey.png)